# python tkinter / classes

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to do a class for all the basic stuff in `tkinter` , it worked but I can't do anything in it. I can't label any text or make a button , can any one help me ?

```
from tkinter import *
try:
    class tkinter_window :
        def __init__(self,color,geo,title):
            root = Tk()
            geo  = root.geometry(geo)
            title = root.title(title)
            color_import = root.configure(background=color)

    def menu_main():
        def welcoming():
            start = tkinter_window("white","400x400","Hunt the number !")
            title_game = Label(start,text="Hunt The Number !",bg="black",fg="red")
            title_game.grid()
            title_game2 = Label(start,text="---------------------", bg="black", fg="red")

        welcoming()
    menu_main()
```

Comment: Where is the ```except....``` block? Also, you might probably want to look up for some ```tkinter``` and ```oop``` tutorials. The most important part ```.mainloop()``` is missing in your code

Comment: please explain what you mean by _I can't do anything in it_? what exactly is the issue? also don't import everything (don't use `*` when importing) and why do you even have it in a `try/except` block? also btw class names should be `CapitalCase` and NOT `snake_case` if you are trying to follow PEP 8, you also actually need to learn the basics of `OOP` and `tkinter`, first of you would usually inherit from `Tk`, that way you could actually pass it as the `master` argument

Comment: Also instead of using `tk.Label(..., text="---------"`), use the `ttk.Separator` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these two lines of code:

```
start = tkinter_window(...)
tile_game = Label(start, ...)
```

In this code, `start` is not a widget. It is an instance of `tkinter_window`. Since it is not a widget, it can't be used as the parent of another widget.

The simple workaround would to be have `root` be an instance attribute of `tkinter_window`, and then use `start.root`.

```
class tkinter_window:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.root = Tk()
        ...
def main_menu():
    def welcoming():
        start = tkinter_window(...)
        title_game = Label(start.root)
```

If you want to be able to use `start` as if it was a real widget, you need to inherit from a real widget. In this case you could inherit from `Tk`. In the following code, notice how `tkinter_window` inherits from `Tk`, calls `super()`, and then uses `self` rather than `root`:

```
class tkinter_window(Tk):
    def __init__(self,color,geo,title):
        super().__init__()
        geo  = self.geometry(geo)
        title = self.title(title)
        color_import = self.configure(background=color)
```

With that,  this code will now work

```
start = tkinter_window(...)
title_game = Label(start, ...)
```

---

Unrelated to the question you asked, your code has a couple other problems. [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is a set of guidelines that almost every python programmer uses, and is part of what makes it so easy to understand python code written by someone else.

A couple of PEP8 guidelines that your code is breaking include:

- [Class names should normally use the CapWords convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)
- [Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Also, there's no need to nest functions the way you've done. It doesn't provide any benefits and makes the code marginally more complex.